# Is there anything wrong with my JavaScript that should return JSON via a Web API (on Azure)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am brand new to JavaScript/Jquery and am having problems with my first "real world" application. For this application I need to download JSON from my Azure Website using the Web API. This is my code:

```
    function returnClientJSON() {
    var value = "novi";
    var valueType = "city";
    //$.getJSON("http://myazuresite.azurewebsites.net/api/location/?q=" + valueType & "&v=" + value,
    $.getJSON("http://myazuresite.azurewebsites.net/api/location/?q=city&v=novi",
    function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            var str = val.Name + ': ' + val.City;

            $('<li/>', { text: str })
            .appendTo($('#clients'));
        });
    });
}
```

I know that the API works because I can get results by going to the URL directly. And with Firebug (I have limited experience using it so I could be missing something) I can tell that the server is not returning any results or any errors that would give me a hint to what is wrong. I also know via Google that this could be an issue with CORS, which I know nothing about.

So I am going to investigate CORS further but I wanted to ask if there is anything obviously wrong with my code above?

Comment: If you're making the request from a different domain than the resource you're requesting, you need to use JSONP. This will require you to configure that web API endpoint to support JSONP.

Comment: The client is a phone gap type application (Icenium) so it is from a different domain. I did find some information about JSONP but I thought that it said I would not be able to post back with it and that using CORS was a better option. So does my JS look ok? Or are you saying that you are 100% sure my problem is a cross domain issue?

Comment: Are you sure the server is returning the JSON you expect? And what does it look like?

Comment: when I hit : http://myazuresite.azurewebsites.net/api/location/?q=city&v=novi ,  I am redirected to http://www.azurewebsites.net/SiteUnavailable.htm , So I guess that you need some sort of authentication before this url return the JSON, hence it isn't a RESTful endpoint suited for getJSON.

Comment: No authentication is needed. I just anonymized the actual site because I didn't want to expose the data yet. I need to clean some of the content before I make the data public. I had thought it was valid JSON but now I am not so sure. Fiddler is saying "The response does not contain valid JSON text" so that is where I will put my focus again. Thanks.

Comment: OK I am very confused. When I browse the URL with FF and Chrome I get XML but when I open it with IE I get this as a result {"Id":300,"Name":"Family Dollar","City":"Lincoln Park","County":"Wayne","Type":"Retail","Address":"100 Main St"}, Isn't that valid JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem that I had was caused by the crossing of domains, I found this article, "[CORS support in ASP.NET Web APIs - RC version](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CORS-support-in-ASPNET-Web-01e9980a)" by Carlos Figueira. I downloaded the sample code, added the included CorsHandler to my project, added the handler to the Global.asax and it just worked.